# Spring boot on embedded tomcat on Apache2 with multiple addresses

Tags: spring, tomcat, apache2

I have a Spring Boot application which runs via its embedded Tomcat on port 8080.

This application must be reached by two different urls, let's say
www.aaa.com and www.bbb.com.

I have apache2 with 2 sites enabled.
This is www.aaa.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost www.aaa.com:80>

        ServerName www.aaa.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

and this is www.bbb.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost www.bbb.com:80>

            ServerName www.bbb.com
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
            ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    </VirtualHost>
```

I can see nothing on both sites...

if i change the VirtualHost in

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

on both conf i can see clearly one of them, but for the second i get a 502 proxy error for all static resource (but the homepage is rendered...)

Which is the correct configuration?

Comment: Is there anything in your Spring Boot app's logs when you get the 502 ?

By the way your correct config is the second one <VirtualHost *:80>